# SQLParse truncates remaining sql after comment is removed

Tags: python, sql, parsing

could you please advise why SQLParse truncates remaining sql after comment is removed?

```
import sqlparse
query = '''/* lala */ -- AS -- DD -- CC SELECT a , b FROM c WHERE d = '2021-01-01' 
           --comment 1
           --comment2
           AND e = '2021-02-03'
           '''
sqlparse.format(query, strip_comments = True)
```

Expected result:

```
SELECT a , b FROM c WHERE d = '2021-01-01' AND e = '2021-02-03'
```

Getting result

```
"AND e = '2021-02-03'\n"
```

Comment: You have a comment starting with `-- AS`, so everything on that line is commented out.

Comment: `--` is used for line comment in SQL, so there's no surprise. How the parser should know what you've *assumed*?

Answer (score 0):

Use /*comment */ instead if you want comment and code in same line, else better code in separate line if you want to use '--' or at end of code